# unable to use deployed contract

Tags: web3js, truffle-contract

I want to use a deployed contract that has been deployed through Mist using byte code.

This is how I try to get the contract using a testnet:

```
import contract from 'truffle-contract';
import Web3 from 'web3';

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}

const existingContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getNetworkAddress",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "addr",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }, ...
], "0x375b2cfB88c3732a14f2AbDD55c561E48c3ff960", { // contract address
    from: '0x749707e9327bc87fd6710de26334bd7003ca15b1', // coinbase
    gasPrice: '20000000000',
    gas: 5000000
});

existingContract.options.data = '0x6060604052...'; // byte code

const test = contract(existingContract);
test.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
test.deployed().then((result) => {
    console.log({result});
    console.log(result.getNetworkAddress.call());
});
```

This gives the following error:

> Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

What am I missing?

Comment: Delete the comments, you have error with it.

Comment: I added the comments only for this post, so you can know what addresses those are. They do not cause errors in the app anyway, just tested it in reality.